# Nativescript Vue: How to get Vue component instance from a {N} View

Tags: vue.js, components, nativescript, instance

I have a RadListView containing some custom Vue components I have made. This component has some kind of prop. A very simple example below

```
<RadListView for="i in 5" ref="listView">
   <v-template>
      <CustomComponent :someProp="Hello"/>
   </v-template>
</RadListView
```

I need to access these props by accessing the children of the ListView. But I can't get the actual component instance whatever I try. I have this so far.

```
this.$refs.listView.nativeView.eachChildView(template => {
    template.eachChildView(component => {
        console.log(component.$props, component.componentInstance.$props) 
        // What to do here??
    })
})
```

Comment: While using ListView you are suppose to play with data and not with actual View. Could you please try to add more details what exactly you are looking for here / why you may need it, possibly there could be alternatives.

Comment: I need some property from the view dynamically when scrolling past it. Which is why I need the view to see if it's within the viewport, and then get the property value if it is.

Comment: You are not suppose to use each child, instead check the last visible index and fetch data from the source by index.